# Does doxygen support inline comments for method arguments in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, comments, inline, doxygen

I used to use doxygen lot for C++, and really like the ability to document function and method arguments inline using `///<` , or variations. Conversely I really *dislike* having to repeat arguments in the comments when not using the inline style (as most over code doc systems only support).

So recently I've been setting up doxygen with my Objective-C code, and can't seem to get inline argument documenting to work!

Out-of-line documenting, using @param, seems to work - so I can only conclude that it doesn't support Objective-C method syntax inline. This would be a real shame.

Does anyone know any different? I'd love to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the syntax that is mentioned in the manual:

```
void foo(int v /**< [in] docs for input parameter v. */);
```

I tested that and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Zitrax, but that's just a plain C function. It's Objective C methods I was hoping to get working.

Answer (score 0):

I rembember having successfully used this notation for instance variables of a class but never tried on method arguments. I suppose this comes from the Objective-C syntax for method arguments.

Comment: Yeah, instance variables are fine, but they're nothing unusual. ObjC methods are certainly different.